# Is the Matrix subset a Subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

If 2×2  is the vector space of  2×2  real matrices.
Let    be the set of all  2×2  matrices whose two columns are orthogonal to one another.

I believe it's(W) **no it is not a subspace** for the 2 following criteria:

1. I believe the all 4 zeroes matrix fails because it's not orthogonal. Although I did want to confirm that the zero vector cannon be orthogonal to itself.
2. The "closed under addition criteria":
   let A = [[a1,a2],[a3,a4]] and B = [[b1,b2],[b3,b4]]

let: a1a2 + a3a4 = 0 and b1b2 + b3b4 = 0; ... because of dot product orthogonality.

but A+B = [[(a1+b1),(a2+b2)],[(a3+b3),(a4+b4)]]
this yields:
(a1+b1)(a2+b2) +(a3+b3)(a4+b4) =

a1a2 + b1b2 + **a1b2**+ **a2b1** + a3a4 + b3b4 + **a3b4** +**a4b3**

The bold ones could be anything even if the non bold yield zero; so via this proof it fails to be orthogonal.

Are my two proofs correct? And if not then is W a subspace?

Comment: You are correct that $W$ is not a subspace. Your methods are on the right track, but if you want to prove that something is not true, the best way is usually to find a counterexample. 

So, try to take concrete matrices from $W$ and see if their sum is in $W$, I'd bet that with high probability, it is not.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was concerned at first picking an example would be less likely to yield that case, but in fact one example proved to be the case! Thank you!

Comment: Note that the usual definition of orthogonal is that the inner product (dot product) is zero. In particular, the zero vector is orthogonal to all vectors, including itself.